# How did Locke, who was Roose Bolton's man, end up in the Night's Watch? What was he planning in S04E05?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In season 3 of Game of Thrones, it was Locke who

> cut off Jaime Lannister's hand.

Locke is one of the men under the command of Roose Bolton. How did he end up in the Night's Watch?

Also, in S04E05, Locke tries to

> abduct Bran Stark when he comes to know of his identity

But since in the same episode

> He is killed by Hodor through Bran

What was his plan exactly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

He was sent there by Roose Bolton. In the second episode of the fourth season, the Boltons found out that Bran and Rickon Stark are still alive (by questioning Theon Greyjoy), which puts their plans for claiming the North in danger. So Ramsay sent Locke to the Wall to keep an eye on Jon Snow, hoping that Jon would lead them to his half-brothers. So as soon as Locke arrives at the Wall he attaches himself to Jon Snow, and it paid off. Locke found Bran and was about to take him away to his masters when he was defeated by Bran's warging.

Comment: Damn! Can't even remember what went down in earlier seasons. I need to rewatch everything after this season's end

Comment: I believe it was Roose who sent him, not Ramsay (at least in the show).

Comment: Note that Locke, and the events at Craster's Keep don't exist in the books.

Comment: @HubertOG - Right, Roose promised Locke a lordship if he could find Bran and Rickon. Also, when Jon Snow asks for volunteers for his ranging, it is mentioned that Locke is still a recruit, so he had only been at the Watch for a short time.

Comment: @GerryColl I haven't read them but someone else told me the same. Why'd they add that then? It's kind of strange to add that part of the storyline if it doesn't actually go anywhere.

Comment: @HubertOG - You are correct, good ser. I shall remedy this immediately.

Comment: @YungHummmma - Without revealing too much of the books, at this point in the story Bran has very little to do. In TV land you can't have a major character disappear from the screen for a long time. So they needed to pad his story a little bit to give him more screen time. It's the same reason for the Theon/Ramsay torture scenes. They don't exist in the books (though they are implied), but were added to keep Theon on screen.

Comment: @SystemDown Haha thanks for being careful of spoilers for us uneducated serfs. I wondered about the Theon/Ramsay scenes too and the only real answer I found was "cause his House likes torturing people."

Comment: @YungHummmma - Oh don't sweat it. The last couple of episodes served up a lot of "not in the books yet" goodness. We book readers are finally in the same boat as the rest of the world, and we're tiptoeing the internet gingerly and wary of spoilers LOL.

Answer (score 2):

He was sent by Roose Bolton to go and find Bran and Rickon Stark:

> Roose Bolton: You ready for a hunt?
>   
> Locke: Always.
>   
> Roose Bolton: **Find those boys** and I'll give you a thousand acres and a holdfast.
>   
> Locke: Your pet rat have any thoughts which way they went after Winterfell?
>   
> Roose Bolton: **Jon Snow is at Castle Black.**
>   
> <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 4 Episode 2, "The Lion and the Rose"</sub>

So in the scene where he tries to abduct Bran, and is subsequently killed, he is trying to take him to Roose Bolton to claim his prize. The scene can be viewed here: